# regex to allow any character but need to accept only single space for entire textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a text box which needs to accept any character but needs to accept only single whitespace for entire text box field but not start with whitespace character.

**Example:**

```
"wall heel" & "wall " & "wall"
```

Here i am posting my code:

```
var alpha = (/^\w+ +\w*$/)||(/^\w*$/);
```

Note:Here it only accepts the characters like `"wall heel"` but not accepts `"wall"`.

Please suggest me some codes.

Comment: is one space required? or optional?

Comment: Is the whitespace allowed at the end of the string?

Answer (score 3):

I think this does the trick for you

```
/^[^ ]+(?: [^ ]+)?$/
```

[See it here on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jJ8eD4)

[image]

Comment: Do you need the square brackets? Wouldn't `/^\S+ ?\S+$/` do the same thing? (Also, perhaps make the last `+` a `*` to allow single character values.)

Comment: You don't need them. Personally, I just think `[ ]` reads better than ` `.

Comment: If you make the last `+` a `*` it allows trailing whitespace, which I don't think is intended (or valid).

Comment: I think trailing whitespace is allowed - at least, the OP doesn't say it isn't allowed. But if not, perhaps `/^\S+([ ]\S+)?$/` instead then? I don't see anything in the requirements about requiring at least two characters.

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern `^[^ ](?!(.*? ){2}).*$`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cD3bS1)

- `^[^ ]` start with a non space character.
- `(?!` negative lookahead.
- `(.*? ){2}` two spaces
- `)` end of lookahead
- `.*$` followed by anything to the end

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is either empty, or does not start with space and have fewer than 2 spaces.

```
var valid = (s == "" || (s[0] != " " && s.split(" ").length < 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regex

```
/^[^\s]+([\s]([^\s]+)?)?$/
```

This will match everything except:

- whitespaces in the beginning (space, tab, new line etc)
- more than 1 whitespaces in total.